# Qt: QMainWindow taking ownership of QMenuBar

Tags: qt, user-interface

I would like to use a single instance of QMenuBar to ease integration with Mac OS X, however the documentation states

> Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of
>   the menuBar pointer and deletes it at
>   the appropriate time.

How can I get all my QMainWindows to share a single QMenuBar? Or is the simple and unfortunate answer "you can't"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for simply quoting the manual, but this question is really already covered on it.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html#menuBar:

> If you want all windows in a Mac
>   application to share one menu bar,
>   don't use this function to create it,
>   because the menu bar created here will
>   have this QMainWindow as its parent.
>   Instead, you must create a menu bar
>   that does not have a parent, which you
>   can then share among all the Mac
>   windows. Create a parent-less menu bar
>   this way:
>
> ```
> QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(0);
> ```

More information about QMenuBar on Mac OS X:

- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x
- http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/mac-differences.html#menu-bar

Comment: "which you can then share among all the Mac windows"... but if the individual windows take ownership of the menu how can they share it?

Comment: You do not associate this menubar with any window. Individual windows will not take ownership of the menu because you will not give it to them. You create a parent-less menubar at one step, then create your QMainWindow in another step. You never call QMainWindow::menubar().

Comment: The QMainWindow ends up not having a menu at all. It doesn't see the null-parent QMenuBar. i.e. I run the application and don't see a menu bar in the window unless I call `setMenuBar(globalMenuBar)`.

Comment: Do not call setMenubar() or menubar() anywhere. Ensure that there is no code calling these methods, specially menubar(), since it will create a blank menubar for that window that will override the global, default menubar.

Comment: I added more links to the answer. Check the last one which explains when windows fall back to using a default menubar, and how the parent-less QMenubar is used as the default menubar for the application.